# Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations (MICE) - Can we also use non-regression methods while inferring missing values?

Tags: mice

Multiple Imputation by Chained Equations (MICE) - Can we also use non-regression methods while inferring missing values?

From the MICE theory I have come across, linear/logistic regression methods have been applied while inferring missing values. Would like to know, if any one tried applying other inference techniques and found anything effective.

Thanks

Comment: [What is MICE?](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/)

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you are asking. Are you asking whether you can use methods other than linear or logistic regression to impute values? The answer is yes, in all MICE software there are many options for imputation. Are you asking whether you can fit models other than linear or logistic regression after multiple imputation? The answer is also yes; you can fit any model after MI and pool the estimates. This is not specific to MICE but any MI procedure. There is nothing special about linear/logistic regression models; they are two of a large family of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind MICE is to sample values of variable $X_i$ from their conditional distribution given all the other variables $X_{-i}$.  You can construct these conditional distributions any way you like. As @Noah points out, the `mice` implementations do provide tree-based predictors in addition to the parametric prediction models.

The main restriction is that you need an entire predictive *distribution* rather than merely a mean. Many predictive models don't automatically come with a predictive distribution, just a best-prediction value. If you want to use a method like that, you need some way to put in the uncertainty from the predictive distribution -- adding in a residual, or using one of the flavours of 'predictive mean matching' to sample from a predictive distribution.

The theory does require (originally, and still, as far as I know) that all the predictive distributions fit together properly to be the conditionals from some single joint distribution. This assumption might well be violated by arbitrary predictive modelling techniques. Fortunately, this assumption doesn't actually seem to matter as much as you might think it should. There's some discussion [here](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-FCS.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!!